# Using AbiEncoderV2 for encoding data in raw transactions

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, nodejs, abi

I've come across a use-case to need to pass a struct into a Solidity function. I know this can be done via tuples. However, I need to sign and send this transaction from my `node.js` back-end using Infura as a provider.

Currently, I use `encodeABI()` from web3.js to encode the function call. However, in this case where it has a struct as a parameter using `encodeABI()` doesn't properly do it, and I'm assuming it's because `encodeABI()` only supports V1 of AbiEncoder.

Is there any functions in web3.js or ethers.js etc. that do what `encodeABI()` does, but using the V2 of AbiEncoder?

I would just pass a flattened struct to get around this problem but I run into the infamous `stack to deep` error, since the struct has 10 values, and I can't separate the function into many functions since the only code is forming the struct inside the function.

EDIT: I realized I could just pass the values in arrays to solve the flattening problem. However, I'm still curious on how to properly encode the data.

Thanks for any help or suggestions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Ethers.js utils to pack the data how the v2 AbiEncoder would:

https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/hashing/#utils--solidity-hashing

Example from the docs:

```
let result = utils.solidityKeccak256([ 'int8', 'bytes1', 'string' ], [ -1, '0x42', 'hello' ]);
console.log(result);
// '0x52d7e6a62ca667228365be2143375d0a2a92a3bd4325dd571609dfdc7026686e'

result = utils.soliditySha256([ 'int8', 'bytes1', 'string' ], [ -1, '0x42', 'hello' ]);
console.log(result);
// '0x1eaebba7999af2691d823bf0c817e635bbe7e89ec7ed32a11e00ca94e86cbf37'

result = utils.solidityPack([ 'int8', 'bytes1', 'string' ], [ -1, '0x42', 'hello' ]);
console.log(result);
// '0xff4268656c6c6f'
```